# Ionic 3 exibe "App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt."

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic3

Eu estou tentando instalar o apk em 2 dispositivos diferentes (Galaxy e LG), mas ambos estão exibindo "App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt.".

Antes eu estava tentando incluir o Login do Google no app, mas estava exibindo o **erro 10**. Após ler vários posts, atualizei alguns pacotes e alterei algumas configurações. O resultado é que não consigo mais instalar meu app.

Como estou gerando o apk:

---

**Passo 1:**

Acesso `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` (JAVA_HOME no meu caso), e rodo:

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
```

**Passo 2:**

Crio um arquivo `release-signing.properties` em platforms/android

```
 keyAlias=alias_name
 keyPassword=password
 storeFile=my-release-key.keystore
 storePassword=password`
```

**Passo 3:**

Vou para o diretório do projeto e rodo (para gerar o apk):

```
 cordova build android --release -- --keystore=platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password`
```

**Passo 4:**

Volto em `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin` (JAVA_HOME), e rodo o comando abaixo para validar o apk:

```
 jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore platforms\android\my-release-key.keystore platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release.apk alias_name`
```

**Passo 5:**

Copio o apk para o Samsung S8+ e LG Stylus 2, tento instalar, mas ambos exibem "App not installed. The package appears to be corrupt."

O que eu já tentei:

---

- Defini as variáveis ​​de ambiente do sistema
- Atualizei as versões do Android Studio, do Android SDK Tools, do Cordova, do NPM e do Node.js
- Atualizei o plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`
- Fiz o downgrade do `build.gradle` para 2.3.3 (e wrapper para 3.3), mas ocorreu um erro durante o build, então voltei ao original
- Alterei os arquivos `config.xml` e`package.json`, para que não contenham  ^ ou ~ na spec do `android` e `cordova-android`

**Ionic info:**

```
 Ionic:

    ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.2
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

 Cordova:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
    Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
    Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2, cordova-plugin-googleplus 7.0.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.0, cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2, cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2, cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3

 System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    NodeJS            : v8.4.0
    npm               : 6.8.0
    OS                : Windows 10
```

**Outras informações:**

- Android Studio 3.3.1
- ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_131
- platforms\android\app\build.gradle:

  ```
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
  }
  ```
- platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties:

  ```
  distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
  ```

**Emulador**

Tentei ainda rodar o emulador, `ionic cordova run android -l -c`, mas também exibiu o seguinte erro:

```
Runtime Error
Unexpected Identifier
Stack
SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier
```

Assim, o resultado é o mesmo, e até agora eu não sei se meu primeiro problema (erro 10 no login do Google) estaria resolvido...

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Tentei fazer o downgrade do Cordova para a versão 7.0.0 e 6.5.0, e android@6.4.0, mas o problema persistiu.

Comment: Voce esta gerando para a produção? `cordova build android` pode ser alterado por `ionic cordova build platform --aot --release --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs
`

Comment: @PéttrinMiranda obrigado pela dica, mas o erro ainda persiste. Estou gerando para instalação direta no device, não ainda para publicação na Play Store (acho que foi essa sua pergunta...).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVV_5LmEg80 , voce provavelmente ja viu isso né?!

Comment: Se não me engano, o que esse app faz é alterar o `android:installLocation` do AndroidManifest.xml para `"internalOnly"`. Nem pelo app e nem manualmente funcionou no meu caso.